# why @angular-devkit/build-angular doesn't install webpack?

Tags: npm, webpack, node-modules, angular7, package.json

I have added latest version of `@angular-devkit/build-angular` in `package.json` and did `npm install` ,it should install `webpack` as well ,as a peer dependency but its not installing ,its throwing a warning explicitly to install webpack when I do `npm install`.I can explicitly install the module but I want that to happen from `@angular-devkit/build-angular`  itself. what could be the reason?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-webpack@0.13.6 requires a peer of webpack@^4.6.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself. @Rust

Comment: saw this on a system where I was doing a side build of an old version and had to downgrade node from 14.X to 12.19.0.  I have a bulid machine where the old build is working on 12.19.  The uninstall/reinstall of node wiped out my globals, so I reinstalled (-g) what was on the build machine globally (@angular/cli@7.1.4, node-gyp@7.1.2).  Same error message you got.  Extra weird part: as a diagnostic, I copied node_modules from the build machine and fixed up _where in package.jsons.  Somewhere during the build THE WEBPACK I COPIED OVER GOT DELETED, then the build complained about not having it.

Comment: small update - an angular 9 build works on the same machine where the angular 7 build is broken (not just on the same machine, but in the same directory, after pulling in the trunk where the branch had been and deleting node_modules).